# Could my migrated question be reinstated here, please

Tags: support, closed-questions, migration

I asked about Mozart as a performer.  It was closed by one person and migrated to music fans.  A great place for the question to sit and rot and not get any attention.

https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6477/as-a-performer-was-mozart-primarily-a-pianist-or-a-violinist

Could we please have it back here where the likely suspects will be able to see it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the question is that it doesn't seem to fit any of our on-topic sections. It does, however, seem to fit in Music Fans.

It is not appropriate to put it on a site where it is off topic just because you think it may get better traffic. That is not a relevant reason. It should be on the site where it is on topic.

We do allow a question which is on topic on multiple sites - if it doesn't get traffic we can move it to another on topic site. In this case, though, it is not about theory or practice.

Additionally, I don't see any reasoning behind thinking it will get no interest on Music Fans. There are lots of questions over there on particular individuals in musical history that get good answers.

Comment: Practice?  Performance is not part of music practice?  I don't think "practice" hear means we are restricted to what happens in the practice room.

Comment: @aparente001 I always interpreted the "practice" in the site's name along these lines: "the actual application or use of an idea, belief, or method as opposed to theories about such application or use." (first definition that I got when I googled the definition of practice).  Part of what is missing from your question is the "application" aspect.

Comment: @aparente001 if this question was about John Lennon instead of Mozart, would you still consider the question on topic here? We should be consistent  with our policies across different styles of music.

Comment: @Dom - Interesting question, but I can't really answer.  I know so little about John Lennon and his music.  (Not that I have anything against it -- I just have never given it much thought or study.)  If you had said Thelonius Monk instead of John Lennon, I'd feel more confident in saying yes.

Comment: I had a typo in an earlier comment.  Everyone has probably figured it out but just in case, I meant: Practice? Performance is not part of music practice? I don't think "practice" here means we are restricted to what happens in the practice room.

Comment: We aren't, however it really will not make any difference to you as a musician what Mozart's main instrument was. It just really has no bearing on anything.

Comment: @DavidBowling - I was simply responding to a question from Dom ("if this question was about John Lennon instead of Mozart, would you still consider the question on topic here?").  Clearly, with respect to Mozart and Monk, I agree with you, and with respect to Lennon, I have no opinion, i.e. I don't disagree.

Comment: @aparente001 that's still a problem because there shouldn't be a perceived difference based on _who_ the question is about.

Comment: @dom - How can I convey this more clearly (because you keep understanding the opposite of what I'm trying to say) -- hmm.  *I don't know enough about Lennon's music to answer the question one way or another* -- so please don't take my non-answer as meaning that I think a question about Lennon would be less on-topic here than a question about Mozart.  That's not what I'm saying.  If you ask me whether I think Product A or Product B will be more effective in preventing male pattern baldness, I will say I don't know enough about it to express an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Music.SE is here to help you with your questions about theory and your problems with musical practice - i.e. if you want to ask about *your* piano and violin playing, this is the place; if you want to ask about someone else's, it may not be.

I say 'may not' because in some cases we might be able to gain some knowledge relating to a composer or performer that we can apply to our own playing, composition, or analysis; Where that's the case, questions about other performers or composers may be on-topic. However, your question about Mozart seems to be more from a general interest perspective - and therefore it's off-topic here, and on-topic on music fans.

I share your frustration that music fans SE is such a complete wasteland. I can only recommend perhaps taking this kind of question to another site altogether - https://www.talkclassical.com/ is one classical site.

Comment: Thanks for the practical suggestion. // I believe that an answer to my question could help us understand performance practice in Mozart's time (and vice versa).  Therefore I think it is a reasonable question for this site.

Comment: @aparente001 so how would a good answer to your question be likely to help me with my own playing, composition, or analysis?

Comment: I don't know what you're playing or analyzing.  But there are lots of ways that understanding performance practice of a period helps with performing music of that period.  This sounds like "Who's buried in Grant's tomb?".

Comment: @aparente001 I agree in general that there are lots of ways that understanding performance practice of a period helps with performing music of that period - I said as much in my answer here. I'm just not sure it's obvious how an answer to this *particular* question would help...